# Python: Extract variables out of namespace

Tags: python, command-line-arguments, argparse

I'm using argparse in python to parse commandline arguments:

```
parser = ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("--a")
parser.add_argument("--b")
parser.add_argument("--c")
args = parser.parse_args()
```

Now I want to do some calculations with `a`, `b`, and `c`. However, I find it tiresome to write `args.a  + args.b + args.c` all the time.

Therefore, I'm extracting those variables:

```
a, b, c = [args.a, args.b, args.c]
```

Such that I can write `a + b + c`.

Is there a more elegant way of doing that?

Manual extraction gets very tedious and error prone when adding many arguments.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you want them as globals, you can do:

```
globals().update(vars(args))
```

If you're in a function and want them as local variables of that function, you can do this in Python 2.x as follows:

```
def foo(args):
   locals().update(vars(args))       
   print a, b, c
   return
   exec ""  # forces Python to use a dict for all local vars
            # does not need to ever be executed!  but assigning
            # to locals() won't work otherwise.
```

This trick doesn't work in Python 3, where `exec` is not a statement, nor likely in other Python variants such as Jython or IronPython.

Overall, though, I would recommend just using a shorter name for the `args` object, or use your clipboard.  :-)

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
It works, but the `exec ""` part feels like a very ugly hack. Why is that necessary?

Comment: Correction: It does not work if the function contains nested functions. In this case the following error message pops up:

        `exec ""
    SyntaxError: unqualified exec is not allowed in function 'main' it contains a nested function with free variables`

Comment: Ick. I did not know that, but it makes sense. Closures require Python's standard local variable mechanism, which accesses locals by index. The use of the `exec` statement anywhere in a function forces Python to use an alternate method of accessing locals by name, because `exec` could define or modify locals (this is also why you can update `locals()` if `exec` is seen in the function, but not otherwise).

Answer (score 0):

You can add things to the local scope by calling `locals()`.  It returns a dictionary that represents the currently available scope.  You can assign values to it as well - `locals()['a'] = 12` will result in `a` being in the local scope with a value of 12.

Comment: You should not modify the return value of `locals()`. It is not guaranteed to have an effect, and usually doesn't in CPython. http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#locals

Comment: Seems that this doesn't work without the `exec ""` trick, that kindall mentioned.