# Is there a pythonic way of assigning values to variables when passed in from the command line?

Tags: python, command-line-arguments, argparse

I have written to following code but it feels very clunky and I was wondering if there was a pythonic way of writing the following code:

```python
import argparse

foo = 0
bar = 1

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("-a", "--foo", type=int,
                    help="foo")
parser.add_argument("-b", "--bar", type=int,
                    help="bar")

args = parser.parse_args()
if args.foo:        # This is the bit that I think is clunky
    foo = args.foo  #
if args.bar:        #
    bar = args.bar  #
```

In my code I have about 7 different arguments and having a list of `if` statements doesn't seem like the best method. Is there a better way of writing this section?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`argparse` have default arguments, so there is no need for the `if`s. Also, you should seperate argument parsing and processing, therefore you don't need local variables for your args, but can use them as parameters. So you would finally get to something like this:

```
import argparse

def some_function(foo, bar):
    pass

def main():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument("-a", "--foo", type=int, default=0,
                        help="foo")
    parser.add_argument("-b", "--bar", type=int, default=1,
                        help="bar")

    args = parser.parse_args()
    some_function(args.foo, args.bar)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Similar questions and answers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24127388/python-argparse-how-to-refer-args-by-their-name/ and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8306171/python-extract-variables-out-of-namespace/

Answer (score 1):

In `argsparse` there are `default` and `required` fields that can help you reduce the amount of `if`'s you have.

Example:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("-a", "--foo", type=int, required=True,
                    help="foo")
parser.add_argument("-b", "--bar", type=int, default=42,
                    help="bar")
```

You can also return the args object, and accessing the args at a later point.